# Calling View Controller Method in ApplicationDelegate - warning me ... but also works

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I need to set my root UIViewController as the delegate for one of its modal child UIViewControllers (runwayAnalysisViewController).  I implemented a delegate protocol which my root UIViewController adopts.

```
[runwayAnalysisViewController setSettingsDelegate: self];
```

(self being the parent UIViewController)

Unfortunately, I am receiving the classic error, "runwayAnalysisViewController may not respond to "-setSettingsDelegate: method."

the delegate is declared as such in the RunwayAnalysisViewController class:

```
id <SettingsRequestDelegate> settingsDelegate;
```

-thence:

```
@property(nonatomic, assign) id <SettingsRequestDelegate> settingsDelegate;
```

it is synthesized in the .m file as well.

I have tried synthesizing the accessor & mutator methods for the delegate as well as manually writing the same but to no avail.

(other attempt, methods declared in interface and implemented as shown:)

```
-(void)setSettingsDelegate:(id)aDelegate {
settingsDelegate = aDelegate;
}
-(id)settingsDelegate {
return settingsDelegate;
}
```

Strangely enough, while this warning persists, I implemented the single method of this delegate as follows:

```
#pragma mark - SettingsRequestDelegate Methods

-(void)userDidRequestSettingsAccess:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"User did request settings access");
}
```

I am able to get a successful message sent from the delegate to the parent UIViewController! Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Are you importing your child controller's *.h file at the beginning of the *.m file of the parent view controller?

(and is the `@property` line you mention contained in that *.h file?)

Comment: yes and yes. It is declared that way. I've also tried:    self.runwayAnalysisController.settingsDelegate = self;

Comment: but then I will then get "not a member of structure or union"  Not really sure why the property isn't synthesizing correctly.

Comment: Update:  the program is compiling with/without warnings spuriously despite cleaning the target.  Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare that your root UIViewController conforms to SettingsRequestDelegate in its header file. So where you currently may have:

```
@interface RootViewController: UIViewController
```

You'll instead want:

```
@interface RootViewController: UIViewController <SettingsRequestDelegate>
```

It's just a warning because in Objective-C all method call dispatches are resolved dynamically and which methods an object responds to can be changed at runtime (albeit not in a very syntactically pretty way). So even though the compiler thinks at compile time that you've probably made a mistake, it isn't really in a position to be certain.

All you're doing with formal protocols is trying to give the compiler something useful to go on for giving you helpful warnings. They weren't in early versions of Objective-C at all and some informal protocols (ie, the delegate has to have certain methods but you document them only in the API documentation — the compiler is completely out of the loop) survived even into early versions of iOS.

Comment: arggh, I wish it was that easy but I already declared that it conforms to the protocol as you described.